# SavedModel file does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to execute this code in google colab for a project of face mask detection but i have a problem with the savedmodel. The code used and the error are bellow.
The training was finished but i can't understand why the saved model wasn't found ( my freind used the same code and she doesn't found any problem with the model), can someone help me? am i missing anything??

```
import tensorflow
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

batch_size=32

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1,
                                                 save_freq=10*batch_size)
import keras

epochs = 50
save_freq=10*batch_size
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'Adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

fitted_model = model.fit(
    train_X,
    train_y,
    epochs = epochs,
    validation_split=0.30,
    callbacks=[cp_callback],
    verbose=1)



import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import face_recognition
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

model=tf.keras.models.load_model('mask_detection.model')


text_dict={0:'Mask ON',1:'No Mask'}
rect_color_dict={0:(0,255,0),1:(0,0,255)}
image=cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/148.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces =face_recognition.face_locations(image,model='hog')

type = isinstance(faces, tuple)

if type == False:
        for face in faces:
            face_location = np.array(face)

            x = face_location[3]
            y = face_location[0]
            w = face_location[1] - face_location[3]
            h = face_location[2] - face_location[0]
            im = image[y:y + w, x:x + w]
            

            grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            resized_image = cv2.resize(grayscale_image, (200, 200))
            imags = []
            imags.append(resized_image)
            imags = np.array(imags) / 255.0
            imags = np.reshape(imags, (imags.shape[0], 200, 200, 1))
            predictions = model.predict(imags)
            predictions = np.argmax(predictions)
            label = predictions
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), rect_color_dict[label], 2)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y - 40), (x + w, y), rect_color_dict[label], -1)
            cv2.putText(image, text_dict[label], (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 0), 2)
else:
        print('no faces detected')
cv2_imshow(image)
```

the error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-17164d330c43> in <module>()
      6 from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
      7 
----> 8 model=tf.keras.models.load_model('mask_detection.model')
      9 
     10 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model(export_dir)
    119         "SavedModel file does not exist at: %s%s{%s|%s}" %
    120         (export_dir, os.path.sep, constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PBTXT,
--> 121          constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
    122 
    123 

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: mask_detection.model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Comment: Looks like you are saving a model with the name `"training_1/cp.ckpt"` and are trying to load a model named `'mask_detection.model'`; better double check on that.

Comment: Also, be careful when saving and loading models between `Colab` sessions since the model data may not be retained.

Comment: That's right the name of the model was the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For benefit of the community

> Looks like you are saving a model with the name "training_1/cp.ckpt"
> and are trying to load a model named 'mask_detection.model'; better
> double check on that. (paraphrased from n1colas.m)

Please make sure you are adding full path of model files and correct extensions of model files before loading them .